# how to display images in gridview on iphone

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone development, what i am doing in my application is i have to disply 20 images in a grid view after 4 tips on images that will be replaced with new images how can i done this please help me

Answer (score 4):

You can d this using UiTableView. Place 4 images one cell by setting frame of UiImageView and add it in cell.

Comment: can u any code add image on uitableviewcell and how to find click image index?

Answer (score 1):

you can display this images in gridview.check the tutorials like
https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView
http://www.zubizubilabs.com/zzgridview.html